# Community site Lightning Web Runtime framework trying to render datasource value in HTML

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-community, lwr

Trying to renders a field as a picklist, with static values in the Community Page LWC, it shows as `Undefined` in JS when I try to print the value..

Below is the code, Can you please help me with what I am missing here?

**Note:** Can able to print the `profileurl` value.

[image]

**meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <!-- Profile -->
            <property name="profileText" label="Profile Text" type="String" default="Profile" />
            <property name="profileurl" label="Profile URL" type="String"
                default="/test?target=profile" />
            <property name="ProfileTargetAttribute" label="Profile Target Attribute" type="String"
                default="_top"
                datasource="_top,_blank" />    

        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**JS:** Printing the value in JS

```
@api ProfileTargetAttribute;

connectedCallback() {
console.log('ProfileTargetAttribute -->' + this.ProfileTargetAttribute);
}
```

**HTML:**
Rendering the value in html

```
Profile -> {profileurl} -> Attribute -> {ProfileTargetAttribute}
```

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. Make sure the case of the property in the JavaScript file matches exactly with the case defined in the meta.xml. If it's defined as ProfileTargetAttribute in meta.xml, it should be the same in the JS file.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Yes it is same, Still not working any idea?

Comment: Could you try a getter setter for the property ProfileTargetAttribute.

Comment: @VivekM tried adding a getter setter still not working

get profileTargetAttributeGetter() {
    return this.profileTargetAttribute;
  }

  set profileTargetAttributeSetter(value) {
    this.profileTargetAttribute = value;
  }